# Rails remote form submitting duplicate form data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

When I submit a remote form in rails, the form `POST` duplicate data, even though if I manually serialize the form using jQuery shows that there are no duplicates.
What could be causing this?

*Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but one of the form data is an array, as a result there are duplicate value in the submitted array.

**Result from chrome's network inspector**
[image]

**Result from jQuery**
[image: Manual]

**UPDATE**
Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/harinsa/112786abc5e14b3fb12d) of my form (removing the html markups):

```
<% @order.available_payment_methods.each do |method| %>
    <%= radio_button_tag "order[payments_attributes][][payment_method_id]", method.id, method == @order.available_payment_methods.first %>
    <%= Spree.t(method.name, :scope => :payment_methods, :default => method.name) %>
    <%= render :partial => "spree/checkout/payment/#{method.method_type}", :locals => { :payment_method => method } %>
<% end %>

# partial 

  <% param_prefix = "payment_source[#{payment_method.id}]" %>

    <%= label_tag "name_on_card_#{payment_method.id}", Spree.t(:name_on_card) %><span class="required">
    <%= text_field_tag "#{param_prefix}[name]", "#{@order.billing_firstname} #{@order.billing_lastname}", { id: "name_on_card_#{payment_method.id}", class:'form-control'} %>

    <% options_hash = Rails.env.production? ? {:autocomplete => 'off'} : {} %>
    <%= text_field_tag "#{param_prefix}[number]", '', options_hash.merge(:id => 'card_number', :class => 'required cardNumber form-control', :size => 19, :maxlength => 19, :autocomplete => "off") %>


    <%= text_field_tag "#{param_prefix}[expiry]", '', :id => 'card_expiry', :class => "required cardExpiry form-control", :placeholder => "MM / YY" %>

    <%= text_field_tag "#{param_prefix}[verification_value]", '', options_hash.merge(:id => 'card_code', :class => 'required cardCode form-control', :size => 5) %>


  <% if @order.bill_address %>
    <%= fields_for "#{param_prefix}[address_attributes]", @order.bill_address do |f| %>
      <%= render :partial => 'spree/address/form_hidden', :locals => { :form => f } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "#{param_prefix}[cc_type]", '', :id => "cc_type", :class => 'ccType' %>
```

**UPDATE** Submitting the form without `remote: true` fixes the problem (BUT I NEED IT!)

Comment: Can you show us your HTML form? I suspect you're replicating the `fields_for` without updating the `id` of each field you add

Comment: Try to send the form without the `remote: true` and check your server logs if there there still be a duplication. Then you will know if it's a `javascript` or a mistake you've done with your `form`

Comment: @RichPeck I have updated the post with a gist of the form.

Comment: @Marwen submitting the form without `remote: true` appears to fix the problem.

Comment: Well there's a problem I can see - let me write an answer

Comment: Well you have it then, maybe there is multiple event listeners `on` the `form` `submit`

Comment: That's one option, I still think the form is hacky though.

Answer (score 0):

Add `onsubmit="return false();"` on your form it will make sure that form is not submited through default form submission. It will be submitted through ajax as you are adding `remote: true`